# Kotlin and Retrofit: HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled only in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I don't understand why it throws me this error when I make a call from a Fragment. If I make the call from MainActivity the code works.

This is the code in the `ViewModel`:

```
fun initialSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest) {
    _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loading
    viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.IO()) {
        try {
            val result = getSyncUseCase.execute(syncRequest)
            _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loaded(SyncItemUiState(result))
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Error(error.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

From the UseCase I call this Repository implementation:

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    var syncResponse = SyncResponse(SpannableStringBuilder(), emptyList())
    if(syncRequest.type==1) {
        val syncNetwork = syncFactory.create(Source.NETWORK).getSync(syncRequest)
        if(syncNetwork.allToday.isNotEmpty()) {
            syncResponse.allToday=syncNetwork.allToday
            syncResponse.dataForView=syncNetwork.dataForView
        }else{
            val syncFirebase = syncFactory.create(Source.FIREBASE).getSync(syncRequest)
            syncResponse.allToday=syncFirebase.allToday
            syncResponse.dataForView=syncFirebase.dataForView
        }
    }
    return syncResponse
}
```

This is the code for manage the API call:

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    val todayAll=todayApi.getTodayAll("all")
    val syncResponse= SyncResponse(SpannableStringBuilder(),todayAll)
    return syncResponse
}
```

And this is the code for the API call:

```
@GET("today/{thePath}")
suspend fun getTodayAll(@Path("thePath") thePath: String?): List<Today?>
```

The ViewModel is catching this error:

> kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled;
> job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@c05b47

I don't understand why I'm having this error when I do this call from one Fragment:

```
val syncRequest = SyncRequest(0, 1,false,false)
syncViewModel.initialSync(syncRequest)
```

And the same call works fine in MainActivity. I'm testing the code in emulator. In the Fragment the code is called when the user click a button.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work by making the call to the `ViewModel` inside `lifecycleScope.launch` something like that:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder()
        val intro = String.format(
            "%s %s%n%s",
            requireActivity().resources.getString(R.string.accept_intro),
            requireActivity().resources.getString(R.string.privacy),
            requireActivity().resources.getString(R.string.terms)
        )
        builder.setMessage(ssb)
            .setPositiveButton(requireActivity().resources.getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                val syncRequest = SyncRequest(0, 1, isNightMode = false, isVoiceOn = false)
                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    syncViewModel.initialSync(syncRequest)
                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton(requireActivity().resources.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
            .apply {
                this@AcceptanceFragmentDialog.isCancelable = true
                setCancelable(true)
            }
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```